# PowerDesigner + Reverse engineering

Tags: database, reverse-engineering, powerdesigner

I am using PowerDesigner to model my SQL Server database. 
I used the reverse engineering option in order to import my database. 
My problem is that the default data in the tables is not imported.

Does anybody know how to import the data in the tables?

Comment: What do you mean by "default data"?  Reference data?  Constrained values?

Comment: I need the data (rows) that is available in the table.

Comment: Which version of PowerDesigner are you using?

Comment: The problem is that there is no default place to store the default data (as opposed to an OO model, where you could create class instances). Maybe create a vbscript function to reverse the values for a table, using the currently defined columns,and storing the INSERT script in a Text extended attribute on the table. Then a custom Method on the model to call this function for each table with less than xxx rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this cannot be done using power designer.

Answer (score 1):

for us such problem obtained too
problem was the name of the table with special symbol ('), after that table description Powerdesigner imports nothing from the script

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reverse engineer a data from the database and store them into a PowerDesigner model.
Instead you are able to define a **Test Data Profile** for each table, column and generate test data (your default data) from PDM to sql-script.

Answer (score 0):

It is not posible directly. However what you can do is next:

- extract the necessary data in `INSERT INTO %TABLE%"(.....` format from some other database client
- Right click on table, click "properties" click "script" tab and again "end" tab and paste your INSERTs there